# Expand JSON field by name rather than number in Power BI/M

Tags: json, powerbi, m

I'm working with the JSON files from Trello in Power BI and I've created a data model, but when I drill into JSON fields, the M generated by Power BI uses the field number rather than the name:

```
let
    Source = #"Json-1-10",
    Value = Source{22}[Value], //This is the line I want to change
    #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(Value, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error)
in
    #"Converted to Table"
```

I want to change the "Value" line to something like this:

```
    Value = Source{"cards"}[Value], //cards is the name of this field
```

Is there a way to modify this M statement so that it expands the field based on the name and not the position? I've tried inserting the field name instead of the number by itself, with quotes, brackets, and I can't seem to get the syntax correct.

Trello recent changed their JSON export layout and removed two fields, so all of the field numbers changed and I had to fix every table in my data model - hoping to avoid that in the future!

Comment: Can you post a sample JSON file so we have something more concrete to work with?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your `#"Json-1-10"` query has been converted into a table.

If you need to keep your data in the converted table structure, you can filter to the relevant row, then drill into the `Value` field:

```
let
    Source = #"Json-1-10",
    Value = Table.SelectRows(Source, each ([Name] = "cards")){0}[Value]
in
    Value
```

Alternatively, and potentially more simply, you can simply reference the Trello JSON directly, without converting to a table first, and drill into a list directly:

```
let
    Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://trello.com/b/yourboardis/yourboardname.json"))[cards]
in
     Source
```